# jquery cycle2 - how to adjust autoheight options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle2

I am using [jQuery cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2) to build a slideshow and am making use of the [autoheight feature/plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/autoheight.php).

I would like to shorten the animation time and looking at [the jquery.cycle2.autoheight.js plugin code](https://github.com/malsup/cycle2/blob/master/src/jquery.cycle2.autoheight.js), I see:

```
$.extend($.fn.cycle.defaults, {
    autoHeight: 0, // setting this option to false disables autoHeight logic
    autoHeightSpeed: 250,
    autoHeightEasing: null
});
```

I am implementing Cycle2 via cdnjs as a CDN, so I can't edit the code directly, what would be the right way to override the `autoHeightSpeed` option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After loading the cycle plugin and before loading the autoheight plugin you could set the defaults

```
$.fn.cycle.defaults.autoHeightSpeed = 432432;
```

Comment: Hm strange, it does seem to set the default correctly but doesn't seem to have any effect

Comment: ah, I see, I need to declare this outside of `$(document).ready(...)` and it works, thank you! http://jsbin.com/loguwu/3/